# Sharepoint Taxonomy Navigation

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, sharepoint-2013, taxonomy

I am using taxonomy for building left navigation in the sharepoint site.
I am using below method for accessing the nodes.

NavigationTermSet navTermSet = TaxonomyNavigation.GetTermSetForWeb(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb, StandardNavigationProviderNames.CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider, true);

but its returning only two terms and not returning all the child terms under these 2 terms.

But if i logging to the site as admin i am able to get the all the child terms as well. 
I tried with console appilcation and its working fine and its problem only with Annonymous user accessing the page.
I have given the Full Access to app pool account also.
Not sure what i am missing here, any lead will be really helpful.

Regards

CR

Answer (score 1):

Try to use RunWithElevatedPrivileges to run with elevated rights.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
    {
    // implementation details omitted
    }
});
```